# What is the accessibility of a process's environment on OS X?

Tags: macos

Are the environment variables of a process running on a modern OS X system accessible to other processes? If so, is this information accessible only to the same user and root?

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14009/95778) answer from Gilles for the same question, except applied to Linux, is exactly the sort of answer I'm looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in how the environment behaves between Linux and OS X, which is a UNIX system.

Comment: There are multiple Linux specifics in that answer ('/proc', memory map code). I'm not willing to take it on faith that because they're both UNIX-like, OS X will be the same. Was hoping for a more detailed answer.